# Python's hasattr sometimes returns incorrect results

Tags: python, properties, attributes, python-2.x, hasattr

Why does `hasattr` say that the instance doesn't have a `foo` attribute?

```
>>> class A(object):
...     @property
...     def foo(self):
...         ErrorErrorError
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> hasattr(a, 'foo')
False
```

I expected:

```
>>> hasattr(a, 'foo')
NameError: name 'ErrorErrorError' is not defined`
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Python 2 implementation of [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) is fairly naive, it just tries to access that attribute and see whether it raises an exception or not.

Unfortunately, `hasattr` will eat any exception type, not just an `AttributeError` matching the name of the attribute which was attempted to access. It caught a `NameError` in the example shown, which causes the incorrect result of `False` to be returned there. To add insult to injury, any unhandled exceptions inside properties will get swallowed, and errors inside property code can get lost, masking bugs.

In Python 3.2+, the behavior has been corrected:

> `hasattr(object, name)`
>
> The arguments are an object and a string. The result is `True` if the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes, `False` if not. (This is implemented by calling `getattr(object, name)` and seeing whether it raises an `AttributeError` or not.)

The fix is [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/2de9d4457082/), but that change didn't get backported.

If the Python 2 behavior causes trouble for you, consider to avoid using `hasattr`; instead you can use a try/except around [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr), catching *only* the `AttributeError` exception type and letting any other exceptions raise unhandled.

Comment: The quote from the Python docs notwithstanding, `hasattr` behaviour may still be considered strange. It's true that arbitrary exceptions inside a property no longer cause the attribute to be considered absent (but rather get raised right in the caller's face), but if an `AttributeError` originates from somewhere within the property, the result of `hasattr` will still be `False`. This may not be intentional. (Or it may, so a property can determine itself whether it wants to be "there".) In any case, executing the property sounds wrong to me in the first place, considering side effects etc.

Comment: There is not really a straightforward way to determine whether an `AttributeError` was raised by the attribute-getting machinery itself, or by code in a property.