# An old-style class works, new-style class broken

Tags: python, range, python-2.x

```
class A_old:
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print 'getattr', attr
        return super(A_old, self).__getattr__(attr)  # <-- note: don't do this!
    def __trunc__(self):
        return 3

class A_new(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        print 'getattr', attr
        return super(A_new, self).__getattr__(attr)
    def __trunc__(self):
        return 3
```

The old-style class works, but the new-style class doesn't.

```
>>> range(A_old())
getattr __int__
[0, 1, 2]
>>> range(A_new())
TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got A_new.
```

Why?

---

<sub>**Note**:  I'm using 2.7 above.  None of this applies in Python 3, where `range` is documented as responding to `__index__` and old-style classes have gone the way of the Norwegian Blue.</sub>

Comment: Something in `range()` catches the `TypeError()` that using `super()` in `A_old.__getattr__()` raises.

Comment: Why isn't `__trunc__` mentioned anywhere in [the datamodel](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)?

Comment: Why isn't `__deepcopy__` or `__copy__` or `__getstate__`? *shrug*. `__trunc__` is really specific to `math.trunc()`.

Comment: OK, why does it catch a `TypeError` instead of catching an `AttributeError`?

Comment: Trying to find out. The shorter method to get this result is using `int()`, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old-style classes implement a different method to test if you can convert to a number, one that supports using `__trunc__` if `__int__` doesn't exist.

`range()` (Python 2), [uses `Py_TYPE(arg)->tp_as_number->nb_int()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1770) to convert the value to an integer, which is *roughly*, but not quite, like using `int()`. So we have to look at the `nb_int()` slot for both old and new-style classes here.

Old-style classes [implement the `nb_int` slot](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/classobject.c#l2180) as [`instance_int()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/classobject.c#l1859), which uses *`hasattr()`* (or rather, the [C equivalent](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/object.html#c.PyObject_HasAttr)) to test for `__int__`:

```
if (PyObject_HasAttr((PyObject*)self, int_name))
    return generic_unary_op(self, int_name);
```

`hasattr()` swallows **all** exceptions, including the `TypeError` your old-style class throws:

```
>>> A_old().__int__
getattr __int__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in __getattr__
TypeError: super() argument 1 must be type, not classobj
```

Because `hasattr()` swallows the exception, `hasattr()` returns `False`:

```
>>> hasattr(A_old(), '__int__')
getattr __int__
False
```

and the next line in `instance_int()` then uses `__trunc__`:

```
truncated = _instance_trunc(self);
```

New-style classes never also use `__trunc__` when you ask for `nb_int`; they want `__int__` or bust. That's because they support slots directly; `tp_as_number->nb_int()` *directly* calls `__int__` if available (bypassing `__getattribute__` altogether).

Note that when explicitly using `int()` to convert, then the underlying C code will look for a `__trunc__` attribute explicitly (using it only if no `tp_as_number->nb_int()` slot is available), but at least it won't use `hasattr()` for this. This means using `int()` on your new-style class still works:

```
>>> int(A_new())
3
```

In Python 3, all use of `__trunc__` treats it as a proper [special method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup).

Comment: Ah, that old [`hasattr` bug](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35566680/674039).